# Cannot deploy .NET 6 preview 5 MAUI Blazor App to physical iOS device

Tags: ios, .net, blazor, maui

You cannot yet deploy a .NET 6 preview 5 Maui Blazor App to physical iOS device. It is not yet available in VS 2019 or VS 2022 Preview as of today.

```
ApplicationVerificationFailed: Failed to verify code signature of /var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/... : 0xe800801c (No code signature found.)
```

Comment: even on a Mac laptop?

Answer (score 1):

See "Build and debug iOS apps" section @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/get-started/first-app?pivots=windows

[image: Build and debug iOS apps]